# Web forms asp.net открыть в Windows Azure

Tags: вёрстка, asp.net, azure

У меня имеется готовый веб-сайт сделанный в visual studio на asp.net. И вот теперь хотелось бы запустить его так сказать в жизнь, но я понимаю что его придется со временем менять, так вот возможно ли управлять готовым веб-сайтом через Windows Azure? как его подсоединить? стоит ли его вообще у себя устанавливать?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем некорректен. Windows Azure является облачным хостингом для веб-приложений. Если под "управлением готовым сайтом" понимается изменение его контента, то вам это нужно делать посредством CMS, на которой сайт создан. Если никакой CMS или панели управления (Админки) на сайте у вас нет, то управление сайтом будет невозможно на любом хостинге. Скорее всего вам придется постоянно менять код и заливать новую версию сайта с каждым изменением.